# How to explicitly disable TLS with PEAR Mail factory?

Tags: php, smtp, pear

Using PHP, I'm attempting to route email through AuthSMTP (a hosted SMTP service).  The problem is that the PEAR mail factory automatically tries to negotiation a TLS connection with the server.  Rather than simply ignoring the attempt, AuthSMTP throws an error.  I need a way to explicitly tell the Mailer class not to try to use TLS.  Any suggestions?

```
    $from = "Example <noreply@example.com>";
    $to = $email;
    $subject = "This is an email";

    $body_text = "plain text here";
    $body_html = "<h1>HTML here!</h1>";

    $headers = array ('From' => $from,
    'To' => $to,
    'Subject' => $subject);

    $mime = new Mail_mime('rn');
    $mime->setTXTBody($body_text);
    $mime->setHTMLBody($body_html);

    $body = $mime->get();
    $hdrs = $mime->headers($headers);

    $host = "mail.authsmtp.com";
    $port = 26;
    $username = "my_username";
    $password = "whatever_password";

    $mailer = Mail::factory('smtp',
    array ('host' => $host,
     'auth' => true,
     'port' => $port,
     'username' => $username,
     'password' => $password));

    if (PEAR::isError($res)) {
        throw new Exception($res->getMessage());
    } else {
        return true;
    }
```

AuthSMTP is giving me the following error:

```
SMTP: Invalid response code received from server (code: 428, response: 4.0.0 Your account is using SSL - either disable it in your email client or enable it at http://control.authsmtp.com)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can't be done with a current release of the PEAR Mail package - but [is a requested feature](http://pear.php.net/bugs/bug.php?id=17513). I've uploaded a patch so that this can be done. Hopefully a new release will be distributed soon.

Comment: Cool.  I appreciate the answer and responsiveness to community feedback.  I'll keep an eye on an updated version for my next project.

Answer (score 6):

The easiest way is to change $tls=true to $tls=false in the definition of the function auth in PEAR\NET\SMTP.php

Comment: This worked for me, I had the same exact problem as the OP. This got rid of the error message for AuthSMTP, but still allowed me to do SSL for sending through GMail and such.  Thanks @Nir !

Answer (score 0):

Switched to using PHPMailer instead and had it working in 5 minutes.